# How to escape '%' character in jinja 2.10 {% trans %} using pybabel?

Tags: python-2.7, escaping, jinja2, translation, python-babel

I am using jinja 2.10 and pybabel. When my template contains following code (with '%' char inside trans block) pybabel-compile does not translate the string. The extracted string (in .po) is OK but on the result page it is not translated at all.

```
<h3 class="title">{% trans %}100% anonymity{% endtrans %}</h3>
```

This code works but the trans-syntax looks better:

```
<h3 class="title">{{ _("100%% anonymity") }}</h3>
```

Also I cannot my bother my translating colleagues with using '%%' instead of '%'.

Comment: I decided to use your `{{ _("100%% anonymity") }}` trick.

Answer (score 0):

Another way: `{% trans percent='%' %}100{{ percent }} anonymity{% endtrans %}`

Answer (score -1):

I had stuck about this too, but I found in Babel [documentation](https://pythonhosted.org/Flask-Babel/) the solution:

```
##flask.ext.babel.gettext(string, **variables)##
##Translates a string with the current locale and passes in the given keyword arguments as mapping to a string formatting string.

gettext(u'Hello World!')
gettext(u'Hello %(name)s!', name='World')
```

And I translate to simple code like this:

```
_('Hello %(name)s!', name='World%')
```

I hope I help you :D