# How do get python to output _("95% confidence interval") correctly?

Tags: python, python-babel

I have a very frustrating issue. I need the string "95% confidence interval" to appear on in a web view. And I need to have it translatable (using babel) so I'm using it like this:

```
_("95% confidence interval")
```

When I do this it treats % c as %c and prevents my .po file from compiling. When I type it as:

```
_("95%% confidence interval")
```

to escape the precent sign it shows 2 percent signs on my web view. How do I type out this string so that it works?

Comment: I've been out of python for a while, but maybe this answer helps https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50806712/how-to-escape-character-in-jinja-2-10-trans-using-pybabel

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried

```
_("95\% confidence interval")
```